# Devexpress Xtragrid TileView

Tags: devexpress, xtragrid

I'm using Devexpress Xtragrid TileView module.

Basically I want my code works like this :

1. user input member ID on the upper left textbox and press load.
2. If they exists, then a Tile will be appeared.
3. A tile should contain : Name, Status, member ID and a photo.
4. If user press load again (either same ID or another ID) a Tile will be added also, and so on. Unless they press Clear & Load, It should be only 1 latest tile left.

So, I'm able to produce up to Step 3.
But I couldn't be able to load the picture.

The picture itself, It's not a byte array. It's a Image path.
e.q : D:/test/1.jpg

So, how do I load the picture?

```
Protected Overridable Sub InitData()
    Try
        Dim homesTable = ds.Tables(0)
        homesTable.Columns.Add("ImageCol")

        For Each row_Renamed As DataRow In homesTable.Rows
            Dim img As Image = Image.FromFile(row_Renamed("memberPhoto")) 'I tried this, but didn't work
            row_Renamed("ImageCol") = img
        Next row_Renamed

        GridControl1.DataSource = homesTable
    Catch
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub setupTile()
    'For i = 0 To j - 1
    Try
        TileView1.BeginUpdate()
        'TileView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        TileView1.OptionsTiles.RowCount = 3
        TileView1.OptionsTiles.Padding = New Padding(20)
        TileView1.OptionsTiles.ItemPadding = New Padding(10)
        TileView1.OptionsTiles.IndentBetweenItems = 20
        TileView1.OptionsTiles.ItemSize = New Size(320, 170)
        TileView1.Appearance.ItemNormal.ForeColor = Color.White
        TileView1.Appearance.ItemNormal.BorderColor = Color.Transparent
        'Setup tiles template
        Dim leftPanel As New TileViewItemElement()
        Dim splitLine As New TileViewItemElement()
        Dim nameCaption As New TileViewItemElement()
        Dim nameValue As New TileViewItemElement()
        Dim statusCaption As New TileViewItemElement()
        Dim statusValue As New TileViewItemElement()
        Dim RGPCaption As New TileViewItemElement()
        Dim RGPvalue As New TileViewItemElement()
        Dim imageTile As New TileViewItemElement()
        TileView1.TileTemplate.Add(leftPanel)
        TileView1.TileTemplate.Add(splitLine)
        TileView1.TileTemplate.Add(nameCaption)
        TileView1.TileTemplate.Add(nameValue)
        TileView1.TileTemplate.Add(statusCaption)
        TileView1.TileTemplate.Add(statusValue)
        TileView1.TileTemplate.Add(RGPCaption)
        TileView1.TileTemplate.Add(RGPvalue)
        TileView1.TileTemplate.Add(imageTile)
        '
        'nameValue.Text = ""
        'statusValue.Text = ""
        'RGPvalue.Text = ""
        'imageTile.Image = Nothing

        '
        leftPanel.StretchVertical = True
        leftPanel.Width = 190
        leftPanel.TextLocation = New Point(-10, 0)
        leftPanel.Appearance.Normal.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(58, 166, 101)
        '
        splitLine.StretchVertical = True
        splitLine.Width = 3
        splitLine.TextAlignment = TileItemContentAlignment.Manual
        splitLine.TextLocation = New Point(190, 0)
        splitLine.Appearance.Normal.BackColor = Color.White
        '
        nameCaption.Text = "Name"
        nameCaption.TextAlignment = TileItemContentAlignment.TopLeft
        nameCaption.Appearance.Normal.FontSizeDelta = -1
        '
        nameValue.Column = TileView1.Columns("preferredName")
        nameValue.AnchorElement = nameCaption
        nameValue.AnchorIndent = 2
        nameValue.MaxWidth = 200
        nameValue.Appearance.Normal.FontStyleDelta = FontStyle.Bold
        'nameValue.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("preferredName").ToString
        '
        statusCaption.Text = "Status"
        statusCaption.AnchorElement = nameValue
        statusCaption.AnchorIndent = 14
        statusCaption.Appearance.Normal.FontSizeDelta = -1
        '
        statusValue.Column = TileView1.Columns("memberStatus")
        statusValue.AnchorElement = statusCaption
        statusValue.AnchorIndent = 2
        statusValue.Appearance.Normal.FontStyleDelta = FontStyle.Bold
        'statusValue.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("memberStatus").ToString
        '
        RGPCaption.Text = "RGP"
        RGPCaption.AnchorElement = nameValue
        RGPCaption.AnchorIndent = 65
        'RGPCaption.TextLocation
        'RGPCaption.Appearance.Normal.FontSizeDelta = -1
        RGPCaption.Appearance.Normal.Font = New Font("Segoe UI Semibold", 12.0F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular)
        '
        RGPvalue.Column = TileView1.Columns("code")
        RGPvalue.AnchorElement = RGPCaption
        RGPvalue.AnchorIndent = 1
        RGPvalue.TextAlignment = TileItemContentAlignment.BottomLeft
        RGPvalue.Appearance.Normal.Font = New Font("Segoe UI Semilight", 25.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular)
        'RGPvalue.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("code").ToString
        '
        imageTile.Column = TileView1.Columns("ImageCol")
        imageTile.ImageSize = New Size(120, 170)
        imageTile.ImageAlignment = TileItemContentAlignment.MiddleRight
        imageTile.ImageScaleMode = TileItemImageScaleMode.Stretch
        imageTile.ImageLocation = New Point(12, 0)

    Catch ex As Exception
        XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        TileView1.EndUpdate()
    End Try
    'Next


End Sub

Private Sub loadBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles loadBtn.Click
        initData()
        setupTile()
End Sub
```

[image: UI]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late but in my case only need to read file from disk and assign to a byte() column.

First of all, table column should be byte array so replace:

`homesTable.Columns.Add("ImageCol")`

for:

`homesTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ImageCol", GetType(Byte)))`

Then I'd try to replace:

`row_Renamed("ImageCol") = img`

for:

`row_Renamed("ImageCol") = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(row_Renamed("memberPhoto"))`

That would load disk file to byte array and shown in tile. I'd check if file exists to avoid exceptions.

That's what I do to load image from disk.

Hope it helps.